# Spring - Redis Cluster Configuration for Redis Hosted in K8s environment

Tags: spring, redis, jedis

I have a multi-master redis cluster configuration hosted in Kubernetes cluster. We connect to the redis via hostname of load balancer using Jedis Library. hostname is prod-redis-cluster.xyz.com. The following is the code I use to connect to the Redis environment.
When there is a patching to redis nodes, IP address of the load balancer does not change whereas the IP address of the actual Redis nodes behind the load balancer changes. However, application loses connectivity to the cluster and it re-establishes only when we restart the application. Is there any other configuration needed here?

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig {

    @Value("${jedis.nodes}")
    private String hostName;


    @Value("${jedis.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${jedis.timeout}")
    private long timeout;



    @Bean
    public RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration() {

        RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
        String[] hostOrPort = hostName.split(":");
        Set<RedisNode> nodeList = new HashSet<>();
        nodeList.add(new RedisNode(hostOrPort[0], Integer.parseInt(hostOrPort[1])));
        redisClusterConfiguration.setClusterNodes(nodeList);

        redisClusterConfiguration.setPassword(password);
        return redisClusterConfiguration;
    }

    @Bean
    public JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig() {
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(50);
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(50);

        poolConfig.setTestOnCreate(true);
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        return poolConfig;
    }

    @Bean("myJedisConnectionFactory")
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration,
                                                         JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig) {
        Duration duration =  Duration.ofMillis(timeout);
        JedisClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder().
                connectTimeout(duration)
                .readTimeout(duration).usePooling()
                .poolConfig(jedisPoolConfig).build();

        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(
                redisClusterConfiguration, clientConfiguration);
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean("redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> getInfo(@Qualifier("myJedisConnectionFactory")
                                                                         JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> template = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();

        template.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();

        return template;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi @jagannathanrajagopalan have you found solution?

Comment: @shami13 No not found. It has solutions with lettuce but not Jedis

Comment: What solution with lettuce have you found?

Comment: Disabling 'dynamicRefreshSources'
Enabling 'enablePeriodicRefresh' and
Having a scheduler inside the application that checks on a period basis that if we don’t have a connection, attempt to create a new one.