# Dynamic Topology refresh in Jedis

Tags: spring, jedis

I have a multi-master redis cluster configuration hosted in Kubernetes cluster. We connect to the redis via hostname of load balancer using Jedis Library. hostname is prod-redis-cluster.xyz.com. T When there is a patching to redis nodes, IP address of the load balancer does not change whereas the IP address of the actual Redis nodes behind the load balancer changes. However, application loses connectivity to the cluster and it re-establishes only when we restart the application.

We use JEDIS Client library. The sample code is present here.

[Spring - Redis Cluster Configuration for Redis Hosted in K8s environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496043/spring-redis-cluster-configuration-for-redis-hosted-in-k8s-environment)

Lettuce client of Jedis provides an option to refresh the topology dynamically at specific intervals. Please refer the below link.

https://lettuce.io/core/release/api/io/lettuce/core/cluster/ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.html

```
redis:
cluster:
 nodes:
lettuce:
  cluster:
    refresh:
      adaptive: true
      period: 5m
timeout: 150

and 

 
`RefreshOptions R = ClusterTopologyRefreshOptions.builder()          
  .dynamicRefreshSources(false).enablePeriodicRefresh(true).build()
```

The above mentioned code helps in resolving the issue in Lettuce. How to achieve the same in Jedis?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure about the specifics of using Spring but I can speak a bit about the Jedis library itself

You will have to investigate the internals of the library and the specific client you are using since there are a few. Specifically you'll be looking to see if your client uses `JedisClusterInfoCache` and if so, how it is used.

I highlighted the relevant portions here which have a scheduled topology refresh: https://github.com/redis/jedis/blob/65d431f549502364bacbc8c25c85e973278c437a/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/JedisClusterInfoCache.java#L72-L84

I understand this question was asked several years ago and it's possible things have changed over time.